# How to remove multiple messages using message selector in JMS

Tags: jms

How to retrieve all messages in a queue which has its header - "UniqueKey='Tomcat-User'" ,

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue,"UniqueKey='Tomcat-User'");
message = consumer.receiveNoWait();
```

Answer (score 1):

simply call `consumer.receiveNoWait();` inside a loop:

```
Message message = null;
while((message = consumer.receiveNoWait()) != null);
```

This would consume all the available messages that matches the selector.