# Does a JMS message selector pull multiple messages down with a single consumer.receive() call or the first message it sees?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm currently using the IBM MQ JMS libraries and writing a Java class that will handle pulling down a message from a consuming queue with a selector like so:

```
consumer = session.createConsumer(queue, "JMSCorrelationID = '" + request.getCorrelationID() + "'");
message = consumer.receive(30000);
```

My question is, if there were two messages in the consuming queue that match the message selector, would calling `consumer.receive` pull down both messages or would it only pull down the first one it sees?

I found this other SO question:
[How to remove multiple messages using message selector in JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080511/how-to-remove-multiple-messages-using-message-selector-in-jms) which seems to allude to the fact that calling receive will pull a single message down even if two messages in the consuming queue match the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of MessageConsumer says the following:

> Receives the next message that arrives within the specified timeout
>   interval.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html

So calling receive should pull down 1 message at a time. It cannot really return more messages as the return type is Message and not any kind of a collection.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't specified how the actual JMS provider client works internally: that's up to the provider; but it can only *return* one message to the caller.